# Is it safe to ignore compiler warning caused by referring to dispatch_queue_t from Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift3

I have an Objective C class which has the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) dispatch_queue_t couchDispatchQueue;
```

I have a Swift extension of that class where I reference that property like so:

```
couchDispatchQueue.async {
```

When I do that, I get the following compiler warning:

> Property type 'OS_dispatch_queue * _Nullable' is incompatible with type 'dispatch_queue_t _Nullable' (aka 'NSObject *') inherited from 'BZCouchDatabase'

I can see why, since my app's generated `App-Swift.h` file has:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) OS_dispatch_queue * _Nullable couchDispatchQueue;
```

while `dispatch_queue_t`is defined as:

```
typedef NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue> *dispatch_queue_t;
```

**Edit**

I've figured out the "further complication" that I was missing in my original description.  This property is required by an Objective C protocol which also requires inheritance from NSObject.  As soon as I make the Swift class inherit from NSObject and conform to the objective C protocol, I get the warning. The following sample code is enough to set off the warning:

Objective C:

```
@protocol Thingness 
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly, nullable) dispatch_queue_t couchDispatchQueue;
@end
```

Swift:

```
class Thing: NSObject, Thingness {
    var couchDispatchQueue: DispatchQueue?
}
```

My question still is: is it safe for me to just silence this warning? Should I file a radar?

Comment: I still can't reproduce. I notice, however, that you have an inconsistency in your claims. On the one hand you declare a property `@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly)`. But the protocol says `@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly, nullable)`. When I bring the protocol and the property into line, and when I acknowledge in my Swift code that this thing is now an Optional, all is well.

Answer (score 1):

Very well described situation — but I can't reproduce it. When I declare

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) dispatch_queue_t couchDispatchQueue;
```

in an Objective-C class file, the generated header shows me

```
open var couchDispatchQueue: DispatchQueue! { get }
```

This is thus seen as a normal Swift 3 DispatchQueue, and my call to `couchDispatchQueue.async` produces no warning at all.

To be clear, I tried it two ways. I declared the `couchDispatchQueue` property in the *.h* file for a Thing class. I imported *Thing.h* into Swift. I then wrote this code in Swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Thing().couchDispatchQueue.async {}
    }
}

extension Thing {
    func test() {
        self.couchDispatchQueue.async {}
    }
}
```

Neither in the straight instance method call nor in the extension do I see any warning.

Comment: That's bizarre!  I've tried removing my derived data and doing a clean and build, and I still get the problem!  Why would my generated header be different?  I'm using Xcode 8.1.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that there is some further complication in your situation that you have not mentioned (because you don't know that it is relevant, and I sure don't know what it is either). :) I'm happy to give you my test project if you like. Wait a moment, I'll stick it in my dropbox...

Comment: I figured out the issue!  See the edit of my question.